# Oracle Forms 6i ORA-01008

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

i try to get some records from DB Package (ORTAK.MERNIS) using its function (GETMERNISINFO(v_var number)) into PLL package type (MERNISLIB.MERNIS_USER).

But I ve a trouble with sending parameter to db package function (:TCK). It throws  ***ORA-01008 : Not all variables bound***

If I set function parameter statically (**ORTAK.MERNIS.GETMERNISINFO(12345678)**), it works as expected.

I use that code in Oracle Forms 6i

Any Ideas?

```
declare
MUSER MERNISLIB.MERNIS_USER;
begin

SELECT TCK,ADI,SOYADI INTO MUSER from table(cast(ORTAK.MERNIS.GETMERNISINFO(:TCK) as ORTAK.TCKTABLE));  

:ADI := MUSER.ADI;
:SOYADI := MUSER.SOYADI;

end;
```

Comment: Where is `:TCK` coming from; does it actually have a value set?

Comment: :TCK is coming from a text_item and it is already set. i ve double checked whether it is null. So it is not empty.

Comment: try `SELECT TCK,ADI,SOYADI INTO MUSER from table(cast(ORTAK.MERNIS.GETMERNISINFO(:TCK)) as ORTAK.TCKTABLE);`

Comment: @simplify_life, occurs syntax error :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like tck is coming from a text input item on the form. Can you try and fully qualify it as :block_name.item_name.

Comment: it is the same. nothing changed . still ora-01008 error occurs

Comment: The error indicates that somehow the :tck variable is not bound to a value. Can you put a statement   message('Value '||:tck);    before the select and after the begin. That will open up a message box in forms to show what value the form has for the variable at that point in execution.

Comment: i ve already put that before.And did it again now.the popup shows the value correctly.so :tck variable is not empty.

Comment: Try assigning the value to a local variable and pass that in instead.

Comment: i ve also tried that! Maybe it is a bug. Or something happens that i missed!

Answer (score 0):

A library can't see the form items :ADI and :SOYADI because there is no guarantee the form the library is attached to will have them.

Use the COPY and NAME_IN functions to populate, or read form block items in a library procedure.